# What are the iPad gestures for the new Chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome

I cannot find the documentation for them anywhere.

Comment: Based on what are you assuming that Chrome for iPad *does* support gestures at all?

Comment: According to a basically all news sites that are reporting the new release. The answer below also provides support that gestures are indeed supported.

Answer (score 2):

Have found only these two:

- switching through open tabs: swipe from the edge of the screen
- change order of tabs: long press on tab and move left/right

Comment: The first case you mentioned seems very anti-iPodish. Swiping from right to left (to me) usually means showing the page to the right. It appears chrome does the opposite. Or is this just my lack of understanding of interface standards?